Integration by parts of a Gaussian function.
I've attempted the following question which involves integration by parts. I've only recently learnt come across this skill, which means there is a very large chance that I'm doing something wrong.
Find $$\int_{-∞}^{∞} Ax^2e^{-x^2/2σ^2} \,dx$$ given that $$\int_{-∞}^{∞} Ae^{-x^2/2σ^2} \,dx =1$$
Using the general form for integration by parts, $$\int_{-∞}^{∞} f(x)g'(x) \,dx=f(x)g(x)-\int_{-∞}^{∞} g(x)f'(x) \,dx$$, I let $f(x)=x^2$, and $g'(x)=Ae^{-x^2/2σ^2}$. Therefore, $f'(x)=2x$ and $g(x)=1$. Substituting these in to the formula, I get $$\int_{-∞}^{∞} Ax^2e^{-x^2/2σ^2} \,dx=x^2-\int_{-∞}^{∞}2x \, dx=x^2-(x^2+c)=-c$$.
However, this is incorrect (I know this because I have to submit the answer and the website, which is Isaac Physics, will tell me whether it is correct or not with no explanation). I don't know where I've gone wrong.

The middle term in your integration by parts formula is incorrect, it should be the limit of the difference as the endpoints go to infinity. Also, $g(x)\neq 1$.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean. As I mentioned, I've only just come across this concept

Integration by parts for this improper integral reads
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g'(x)~dx = \lim_{b\to\infty}\lim_{a\to-\infty}f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a) - \int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x)g(x)~dx.
$$
The middle term corresponds to the limit as the endpoints go to $\pm\infty$ of the difference $f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)$. The integral you start with basically tells you that $\lim_{b\to\infty}\lim_{a\to-\infty} g(b)-g(a) = 1$. If you apply integration by parts with the choices of $f$ and $g$ you started with, the middle term reads
$$
\lim_{b\to\infty}\lim_{a\to-\infty}b^2g(b) - a^2g(a),
$$
which does not exist. However, if you choose $f(x) = x$ and $g'(x) = Axe^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}$, you will get limits that exist and can proceed as in this answer.

This answer is unclear, and he can't proceed "as in the answer" as you claim. What is $g(x)$ ? This is why it is not clear. The antiderivative of $g'(x)$ does not exist.
